# Add and update language file array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I can get language array from this function

```php
$array = Lang::get('msg'); // return entire array
$text  = Lang::get('msg.success'); // return single item
```

or

```php
$array = trans('msg'); // return entire array
$text = trans('msg.success'); // return single item
```

But now I want to add/update a new key value to this msg.php language file from controller.

how can I do this?

I have tried to `Lang::set()` but there is no helper function like this.

Comment: there is a `Lang::addLines` method but it isn't going to save it to the file, just add it to the current locale's translations for the current request

Comment: I have to manage(read/write/delete) on file. how can i do this? give me some suggestion thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [JSON-based translations in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys).
Then you'd have one json file per each language. For example, English would be stored in `resources/lang/en.json`. Since it's just a json file, you can easily write to it via `file_put_contents()` and `json_encode()`.

UPD: Turned out that the language changes should be per-user. Then then solution is to have a separate table in the DB which would hold the strings along with user_id. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
function mytrans($string, $user_id) {
 if translation exists in the table for this user_id
    return translation
 else
    return trans(string);
}
```

Comment: I have to change back-end messages like validation message. that exists in validation.php  file. and other customize messages.I am already use an en.json/bn.json/hi.json for plain text. but when it's back-messages that's not work by this.

Comment: Then why can't you just change it in `validation.php` file directly? Why do you need to do it via PHP code?

Comment: In my project user can add language as many as he want so when add a new language user have to change every time in every file- it's not disgusted? . so I want to give user full language management feature.an user an update the messages that he want

Comment: Then your solution would be to have a separate table in the DB which would hold the strings along with `user_id`, and you should use a custom function that checks that table first, then if nothing found returns the default translation via `trans()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package for manage Language.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

It is very easy to use.try it